GNOME Apps does not open on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
So, I'm new to Ubuntu for about a month and I was using the GNOME Web browser (epiphany), and this past week, the browser and other GNOME apps, like Apostrophe and even the GNOME Store, stop opening. I click on it, and the cursor spins, spins, spins, and nothing happen.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

I had the same issue on ubuntu 24.10 ...
at first I had the flatpak version installed, that didn't run.
Then I switched to nstalling the .deb version, that one works.
you can try this on 24.04, by deleting ephinany by clicking the trash button in the software center, and under that trash button you can select the source. change that to .deb and install it again. Good Luck
